# Confusion of classification of closed surfaces

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, klein-bottle, mobius-band

I read that we can distinguish closed topological spaces without boundary up to homeomorphism by orientability and euler characteristic - is this correct?

But what confuses me is that the Klein bottle and the Mobius band are both non-orientable and both have Euler characteristic 0. But I thought theses spaces were not homeomorphic?

Please could you help me with this?

Comment: How do you distinguish a circle from a torus?  Both have Euler characteristic $0$ and are orientable.

Comment: That is my question

Comment: you can distinguish **2 dimensional closed topological manifolds** using orientation and euler char.

$0$ and $1$ dim closed manifolds are even easier

Answer (score 4):

The Möbius band has a boundary, and therefore doesn't give a contradiction to the statement.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably a stupid question, but why does the Klein bottle not have a boundary, since it is a finite closed surface?

Comment: @amiz9 Be careful, the (differential geometric) boundary of a manifold is not the same concept as the (topological) boundary of an embedding of the same manifold in some Euclidean space. For example, the sphere $S^2$ has no boundary as a manifold, but if you look at it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it has a boundary as a topological subset. Does this help?